# something wrong reading XML LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

This is my source XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="1.04">
<CTe>
<infCte versao="1.04" Id="CTe35121004211559000111570010000118991000119858">
<ide>
     <cUF>35</cUF>
     <cCT>00011985</cCT>
     <CFOP>7358</CFOP>
     <natOp>PRESTACAO DE SERVICO DE TRANSPORTE</natOp>
     <forPag>1</forPag>
     <mod>57</mod>
     <serie>1</serie>
     <nCT>11899</nCT>
     <dhEmi>2012-10-01T09:34:45</dhEmi>
</ide>
<compl>
<emit>
<rem>
<dest>
<vPrest>
<imp>
<infCTeNorm>
</infCte>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
</CTe>
<protCTe versao="1.04">
</cteProc>
```

I have read this file with this code :

```
      XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Separados\56000858_v01.04-procCTe.xml");
        XmlNodeType type;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            type = reader.NodeType;
            if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                if (reader.Name == "cUF")
                {  reader.Read(); Xmunini = reader.Value; textBox1.Text = Xmunini;}

                if (reader.Name == "cCT")
                {  reader.Read(); vtprest = reader.Value; textBox2.Text = vtprest;}

                if (reader.Name == "natOp")
                {   reader.Read(); UFIni = reader.Value; textBox3.Text = UFIni; }

                if (reader.Name == "nCT")
                { reader.Read(); NCT = reader.Value; textBox4.Text = NCT;}
```

But,  i have read in many post here , the method with LINQ is more efficient, i have try write this :

```
    var custs45 = from c in XElement.Load(@"C:\Separados\56000858_v01.04-procCTe.xml").Elements("Cte")

    select new { 
    CFOP = c.Element("CFOP").Value,
    xMunIni = c.Element("xMunIni").Value 
    };
```

My question is how to assign CFOP and Xmunini to a variable?? i have write this but do not show anything

```
    string CFF;
    foreach (var valores in custs45)
    { 
      CFF = valores.CFOP.ToString() ;        
    }
```

Comment: What are `+, -, --` in your xml? Where is closing tag for root node? Where are other closing tags?

Comment: Please format properly your XML sample.

Comment: by any chance, was that xml copied from Internet Explorer?

Comment: I have edited the XML source file , sorry i have copied from IE

Comment: This XML is still invalid. You have mismatched open and close tags.

Comment: Also, you have only accepted one answer out of 13 eligible questions in the past. Please take the time to accept answers to show us that you actually care to have your questions answered.

Comment: Now is valid , i have fix the tag <infCte></infCte>

Comment: I have confirm the answers of the question, many of them i have answer .

Comment: No, this is still invalid. Please open your XML in an XML editor of some kind? Anything from Visual Studio to XMLSpy will tell you this is bogus XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find nodes, because root node has namespace delcared. Here is the solution:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte";
string CFF = (string)xdoc.Descendants(ns + "CFOP").Single();
```

Also you have typo in `CTe` element name. And you are missing that `CFOP` is not direct child of `CTe`. And there is still no `xMunIni` element in your xml.

Your original query should look like this:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte";
var custs45 = from ide in XElement.Load(path_to_xml).Descendants(ns + "ide")
              select new
              {
                  CFOP = (string)ide.Element(ns + "CFOP"),
                  xMunIni = (string)ide.Element(ns + "xMunIni")
              };
```